# Running ansible lineinfile twice is adding a line at the end of the file

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have a ansible playbook and I want to change a configuration for postgres database:

```
...
- name: Configuring postgres
  become: yes
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf
    regexp: "^local   all             postgres                                peer$"
    line:   "local   all             postgres                                trust"
....
```

I want to replace **peer** with **trust**

in the postgres configuration. When I run the playbook for the first time it works fine as expected. But when I run it 2 or more times, the playbook starts append a new line at the bottom of the file, since the search string is no longer false. How do I prevent ansible from doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `backrefs: yes` to make it **idempotent**.

```
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf
    backrefs: yes
    regexp: "^local   all             postgres                                peer$"
    line:   "local   all             postgres                                trust"
```

From: [lineinfile](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html)

**backrefs**

> If the regexp doesn't match anywhere in the file, the file will be
>   left unchanged. If the regexp does match, the last matching line will
>   be replaced by the expanded line parameter.